# Flare Flutter Animations

Tags: flutter

Animations created with Flare Flutter (from 2dimensions.com) cannot switch between different animations of the same Flare Actor. If a black version is first, the white version will not display; if the white version is first, the black will display.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it is a bug. It can switch between colors, just not animations.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

const List<String> animations = ['White', 'Black'];
const List<Color> colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.black];

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Animation Tester',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Animation Tester'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int index = 0;
  void switchAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      index = index < (animations.length - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(index);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: switchAnimation,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 100.0,
              )),
          Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              child: FlareActor(
                'assets/color_wheel_loading.flr',
                color: colors[index],
              )),
          Container(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 200.0,
              child: FlareActor(
                'assets/color_wheel_loading.flr',
                animation: animations[index],
              )),
          Center(child: Text('$index'))
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code with my own file, it works perfect. May be your animation names are not right, can you check.

Or you can test this file "https://www.2dimensions.com/a/whitewolfnegizzz/files/flare/pj"  and using  the code below.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flare_flutter/flare_actor.dart';

```
const List<String> animations = ['Build and Fade Out', 'Build'];
const List<Color> colors = [Colors.blue, Colors.black];

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Animation Tester',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Animation Tester'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int index = 0;
  void switchAnimation() {
    setState(() {
      index = index < (animations.length - 1) ? index + 1 : 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(index);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: switchAnimation,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 100.0,
                  )),
              Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: FlareActor(
                    'assets/color_wheel_loading.flr',
                    color: colors[index],
                  )),
              Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  child: FlareActor(
                    'assets/Pj.flr',
                    animation: animations[index],
                  )),
              Center(child: Text('$index'))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i observed, Flare animation names are case sensitive. If the animation names in the flare project are in lowercase, the animation property of your flare actor should also be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add flr in assets.
2. initialize it in Pubsepec.yaml file
3. then add dependency of flare animation in pubsepec.yaml file

after this,

just use this code in your main file

```
Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *0.8,
          child: FlareActor(
            'assets/oncemore.flr',
            animation: 'Celebrate Duplicate',    // Check this, when you are downloading flr file from Flare 2D dimension website
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
```

After this , Your Flare animation will work perfectly.